# How to Resize InDesign Document and Reflow Text

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize

I have an InDesign document; 100 or so pages of text, no images. I'd like to resize the document from A4 to 6 in x 9 in. Or 5 x 8.

Going to `File > Document Setup` lets me easily change the page size, but then the text remains outside the margins and does not flow. The text is not affected.

Adjust layout doesn't work. Liquid Layout doesn't work. The Adjust Layout VB script doesn't work either.

Cut and paste into a new document didn't work because there was no autoflow of text and creation of additional pages.

Place text (from the indd file) didn't work either. All I could see was the last page of the text from the larger size file on a single page in the target file, with no way to expand the number of pages or autoflow the text. 
There has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: "Adjust layout doesn't work" - you mean enabling "Layout Adjustment"? That can only work if your *text frames* are actually touching the margins. If you did not use the standard margins, you may be able to get it to work if you change the margins first to match your text frames.

Comment: The text frame fills the full page on all the 100+ pages. So it doesn't work. The margins must fill the text pages on the resized pages.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to accomplish this: Create a new document with your new page size and margins the way you want them.

In the New Document dialog box check the box for Primary Text Frame and a text frame is automatically placed on all pages that aligns to the margins and are linked together.

Next copy all of your text from the old document and paste into the first frame and it will reflow throughout the document.

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that the master pages are all lost. Though there were only three, the formatting distinctions among each of them are important.

Comment: You can copy the 3 master pages over to the new document, but then will need to resize them manually (select the master you want to move or copy. Choose Layout > Pages > Move Master, and choose the destination document name from the Move To menu - from InDesign help.) But then you are still left to manually apply each page to the master B and C (after applying A to all). Good luck.